# HDCP Error on Dual Monitor when one is turned off

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, drm, hdcp

I'm trying to watch a movie on Amazon Prime Instant Video.
Unfortunately HDCP and consequently HD/UHD playback is not working if I turn off my second screen. As soon as I turn it on, HD playback IS WORKING. BUT if I unplug the second screen from my Graphics Card HDCP is working fine.

My setup:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Radeon HD7950
- Primary screen: Samsung U28E850R (Display Port 1.2)
- Secondary screen: Benq G2222HDL (DVI-I)

In my opinion there is no understandable reason for such a behaviour.

I guess this is why people pirate movies and tv-shows...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue with the HD7970 and one monitor over DVI. I am going to guess that is the cause...

Comment: The only workaround I found is to disable the monitor temporarily in the Windows Display Settings :/